# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on CCLabelBMFont dealloc?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

On `CCLabelBMFont`, I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on its `dealloc` method. Specifically, line `[configuration_ release];`

I do not understand that at all. What could possibly cause that? My CCLabelBMFont was created alright, displayed alright, and when it is dealloced (when the scene is replaced), bang, the error comes.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace `0x543216` with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

[See this article for more detailed instructions.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: Thank you. I enabled those variables and guard malloc. Now the app crashes on the very very beginning (splash screen). It does log a warning though: *warning: Couldn't get real path for inserted library /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.1/Symbols/usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib*   Yeah, I am developing for 4.1 for now.

Comment: Ah, turns out it only works on simulator huh. Anyway, I did it now, and got quite a nice stack of info. Do you have any more tips about this? Because I am probably as confused as before: got no clue what the problem is :(

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace from the console into the question?

Comment: Well, I am not entirely sure what actually happened, but I suspect: On the dealloc method of my scene I placed some lines that released some objects that were children in the scene. I think that the error came up because, when the scene was dealloced, it would try to release all its children as well. But since it tried to release something I already released, an error would pop.

Comment: Not sure though. This still kind of puzzles me. I will research further.

Anyway, thank you for teaching me that Malloc stuff. It seems pretty useful :)

Comment: @Omega happy to help.  Good luck, hope all goes well with the rest of your coding adventures :).